# IntelliJ-Idea disable inspection: Actual value of parameter is always

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-analysis

Is there a way to disable this inspection? I know, this maybe be a bad design, but I still would like to disable it.

Comment: Why vote negatively for the question? Please explain.

Comment: What inspection do you mean? Please explain.

Comment: This inspection checks all calls to a function, and if it finds that in all calls the value of this parameter is the same, it issues a warning.  This is a nuisance in case I have not written enough code, and I do not want such warnings to clog my Problems list.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Find an instance of the inspection, and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to open the content menu. You'll see a suggestion there that looks like "Inline value 'XYZ' for parameter 'myParameter'". Click the right arrow next to it to open a second context menu, and there you'll find options to edit the inspection setting in order to tune the conditions that will produce it, suppress it for the method/class/parameter, or even disable it altogether.

Answer (score 18):

@SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")

I tested it in Android Studio 3.5, which is based on IntelliJ-Idea, so it probably works in other IntelliJ-Idea based IDEs too.

Comment: this is IMHO the solution

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2023.1.3 on Win10: check

Answer (score 7):

Use `@SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")` in `java`

and `@Suppress("SameParameterValue")` in `kotlin`

Tested on `Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1`